# Cake 3.x Validation - Creating Reusable Validators

Tags: php, validation, cakephp

I am working on cakephp 3.x and i am trying to validate user change password form.
So here i tried to create a separate class for validation see the code below

**UserValidator**
 In constructor i defined some validation rules.

```
<?php
namespace App\Model\Validation;

use Cake\Validation\Validator;

class UsersValidator extends Validator
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        // Add validation rules here.
        $this
            ->requirePresence('old_password')
            ->notEmpty('old_password');

        $this
            ->requirePresence('password')
            ->notEmpty('password');

        $this
            ->requirePresence('confirm_password')
            ->notEmpty('confirm_password');
    }

    public function validateChangePasswordForm(){

    }

}
```

**UserModel**
Where i am trying to use it ...

```
<?php
namespace Accounts\Model\Table;
use Accounts\Model\Entity\User;
use Cake\ORM\Query;
use Cake\ORM\RulesChecker;
use Cake\ORM\Table;
use Cake\Validation\Validation;
use Cake\Validation\Validator;
use App\Model\Validation\UsersValidator;
/**
 * Users Model
 *
 * @property \Cake\ORM\Association\BelongsTo $Roles
 */
class UsersTable extends Table
{
    /**
     * Initialize method
     *
     * @param array $config The configuration for the Table.
     * @return void
     */
    public function initialize(array $config)
    {
        parent::initialize($config);
        $this->table('users');
        $this->displayField('first_name');
        $this->primaryKey('id');
        $this->addBehavior('Timestamp');
        $this->belongsTo('Roles', [
            'foreignKey' => 'role_id',
            'joinType' => 'LEFT',
            'className' => 'Accounts.Roles',
        ]);
        $this->hasOne('Profiles', [
            'foreignKey' => 'user_id',
            'className' => 'Accounts.Profiles',
            'dependent' => true
        ]);
    }
    /**
     * Default validation rules.
     *
     * @param \Cake\Validation\Validator $validator Validator instance.
     * @return \Cake\Validation\Validator
     */
    public function validationChangepass(UsersValidator $validator)
    {
        return $validator;
    }
    public function validationDefault(Validator $validator)
    {
        $validator
            ->integer('id')
            ->allowEmpty('id', 'create');

        return $validator;
    }
    /**
     * Returns a rules checker object that will be used for validating
     * application integrity.
     *
     * @param \Cake\ORM\RulesChecker $rules The rules object to be modified.
     * @return \Cake\ORM\RulesChecker
     */
    public function buildRules(RulesChecker $rules)
    {
        $rules->add($rules->isUnique(['email']));
        $rules->add($rules->isUnique(['username']));
        $rules->add($rules->existsIn(['role_id'], 'Roles'));
        return $rules;
    }
    public function beforeSave($event, $entity, $options){
        if($entity->first_name)
            $entity->slug = $this->createSlug($entity->first_name);
    }
}
```

**User Change Password Form**

```
<div class="users form large-9 medium-8 columns content">

    <?php echo $this->Form->create($user, ['context' => ['validator' => 'Changepass']]); ?>
    <fieldset>
        <legend><?= __('ChangePassword') ?></legend>
        <?php echo $this->Form->input('old_password', ['autocomplete'=>'off' ]) ?>
        <?php echo $this->Form->input('password', ['label'=>'New Password', 'autocomplete'=>false]) ?>
        <?php echo $this->Form->input('confirm_password', ['label'=>'Re-Enter Password']) ?>
    </fieldset>
    <?= $this->Form->button(__('Submit')) ?>
    <?= $this->Form->end() ?>
</div>
```

**Errors**

Warning (4096): Argument 1 passed to Accounts\Model\Table\UsersTable::validationChangepass() must be an instance of App\Model\Validation\UsersValidator, instance of Cake\Validation\Validator given, called in C:\wamp\www\comsats-lounge\vendor\cakephp\cakephp\src\Validation\ValidatorAwareTrait.php on line 106 and defined [ROOT\plugins\Accounts\src\Model\Table\UsersTable.php, line 55]

I have try to overcome on this warning. Please suggest me a solution.

**Link That i followed**

http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/core-libraries/validation.html#creating-reusable-validators

Answer (score 0):

In your `UsersTable` change the signature

```
public function validationChangepass(UsersValidator $validator)
```

to

```
public function validationChangepass(Validator $validator)
```

Comment: I have tried but this time error changed .

This is how i tried .

Error: Class 'App\Model\Validation\UsersValidator' not found 
File C:\wamp\www\comsats-lounge\plugins\Accounts\src\Model\Table\UsersTable.php 
Line: 58


public function validationChangepass(Validator $validator)
    {

        return new UsersValidator();
    }
`

Comment: You should learn OOP and namespaces in php and more important learn how to read and work with error messages. If every error message make you struggle something went terrible wrong in your education. Google that error message and *understand* the cause by reading the namespace section of the php manual.

Comment: Thanks man i had already solved my problem . Again thanks for helping :)